# SQL - How do I sort by an highest value of one column grouped by an identifying column?

Tags: sql-server

SQL outputs this when ordering by DepartmentNumber then by NumberOfWriteUps desc:

```
DepartmentNumber    Name    NumberOfWriteUps
    1               Kiley           4
    1               Jon             1
    1               Brandon         0
    2               Kendra          3
    2               Jake            1
    2               Keegan          0
    3               Shelly          5
    3               Andy            1
    4               Andrew          0
```

What I want is for the below output from SQL:

```
DepartmentNumber    Name    NumberOfWriteUps
3                   Shelly          5
3                   Andy            1
1                   Kiley           4
1                   Jon             1
1                   Brandon         0
2                   Kendra          3
2                   Jake            1
2                   Keegan          0
4                   Andrew          0
```

So ordering by highest NumberOfWriteUps first but within the same DepartmentNumber following the highest of NumberOfWriteUps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps with the window function `max() over()`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Order By max([NumberOfWriteUps]) over (partition by [DepartmentNumber]) Desc
         ,NumberOfWriteUps Desc
```

**Returns**

```
DepartmentNumber    Name    NumberOfWriteUps
3                   Shelly  5
3                   Andy    1
1                   Kiley   4
1                   Jon     1
1                   Brandon 0
2                   Kendra  3
2                   Jake    1
2                   Keegan  0
4                   Andrew  0
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thank you John!

Comment: @BumperBlakie Always happy to help  :)